# Failed compilation of php 7 with-gnupg on centos 7

Tags: php, gnupg

With reference to [Compiling PECL extensions statically into PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.static.php).

I am trying to make a compilation of PHP 7.0.13 with --with-gnupg (gnupg-1.4.0):

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php7013 --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=lighttpd2 --with-fpm-group=lighttpd2  --enable-bcmath --with-gnupg
```

Part of the output regarding gnupg:

```
checking for gnupg support... yes
checking for gnupg files in default path... found in /usr/include
checking for gpgme_check_version in -lgpgme... yes
checking for gpg... /usr/bin/gpg
```

But then it fails with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ext/gnupg/gnupg_keylistiterator.o: undefined reference to symbol 'gpg_strerror'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'gpg_strerror' is defined in DSO /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib64/libgpg-error.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I can help you with your issue, but are you really compiling against GnuPG 1.4.0? That release is twelve years old and has several known vulnerabilities. The GnuPG classic branch is currently at 1.4.14. If you're really using a release that old, switching to the newest release might also fix the compilation issues.

Comment: @JensErat  I mean is version of extension of PHP [https://pecl.php.net/package/gnupg](https://pecl.php.net/package/gnupg). Currently 1.4.0 is highest version of extension, released at 2016-08-29. But! Many thanks, because with your help I found something interesting: I have installed gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.22. And docs of extension have a README where says: **The extension supports only gnupg version 1 and the version 2 is not currently supported**. It should be fixed in the extension version 1.5. So, I will try to install a GnuPG version 1.4.14

Comment: Looking at Debian's `php5-gnupg` package and it's build dependencies, I'd say GnupG 2.0/2.1 is totally fine. Furthermore, you need the `gpgme` package (and it's headers) and `libgnupg-error` (and headers). The packages might be called differently on other operating systems.